# Vandalism of one's own questions

Tags: discussion

The user "SuperTroll" has recently been vandalizing their own questions, see their user page for many examples: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/94756/supertroll

It does not appear SuperTroll has been giving any good reason for this vandalism.  Given the possibility they are trying to cover their tracks, perhaps we should revert the edits?

I imagine there's some discussion on this topic already but my brief search did not discover any.

Comment: I'm sorry, but, what does "vandalizing" means?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandalism

Comment: (this brought a crooked smile to my face) Thanks. What do you mean with "cover their tracks"?

Comment: It seems disappointing that someone cannot edit his own questions as they wish. And also the seizure of contents in [*3. Subscriber Content*](http://stackexchange.com/legal).

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cover+one%27s+tracks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The standard practice is to flag the post for moderator attention. We take vandalism of one's own content very seriously. If you're comfortable with it, feel free to revert the edits; otherwise the moderators probably will.

Comment: It seems to have been done already, thanks.

Comment: The user has been deleted. But so have all of their questions. (Which probably is what they wanted in the first place.) Hopefully they can be restored (with the obvious exception).

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I'm in the process of restoring them. I deleted the user as thoroughly as I could, but that has the side effect of deleting their questions.

Comment: I imagine that's what happened. Nuclear deterrent.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I've restored those I'm aware of, let me know if there are any I've missed that you know of.

Comment: (Which reminds me: Is there a way to request undeletion of an answer deleted by a moderator *before they were moderators*? My impression is that the answer was deleted for a fixed amount of time, and then they forgot to restore it, and now it sits there, and other users cannot vote to undelete.)

Comment: This one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494030/can-you-please-help-me-understand-a-part-of-this-proof

Comment: @AndresCaicedo You mean a non-moderator was one of the three users who voted to delete an answer, then the user became a moderator and the deletion vote is now locked? If so, I wasn't aware that would happen and would consider it a bug. But in individual cases you can always flag a post and leave us a note explaining the situation.

Comment: (I mean a non-moderator who self deleted their own answer purportedly for a while, then became a moderator. I will flag the post.)

Comment: (Flagged.${}{}$)

Comment: (Thank you! Feel free to delete these off topics comments.)